# How to get geom_point size to reflect actual values rather than relative values

Tags: r

There is probably a simple solution to this, but I'm too much of a newcomer to know what it is - so I'd greatly appreciate any help.

I'm trying to create a graph that will show the average time to first response vs. the response rate. However, I want each point size to represent the actual size (no. active users in the table below) rather than the relative size.

Data frame table:

[image]

```
ggplot(benchmarksdf, aes(benchmarksdf$`Avg. Time To First Response`,benchmarksdf$`Response Rate`)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, aes(fill=benchmarksdf$`Community Name`, size=benchmarksdf$`Active Users`)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=benchmarksdf$`Community Name`), check_overlap = T, show.legend = F, size = 3, vjust = 2) +
  labs(title = "Benchmarking Top Enterprise Communities", 
       subtitle = "Comparing top brand communities by response rate and avg. time to first response",
       y = "Response Rate %",
       x = "Avg. time to first response (days)") + scale_x_reverse () +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none',aspect.ratio = 0.8)
```

This leads into this result below:

Gggplot of community by size:

[image]

My eyes could be deceiving me, but at the moment the size of each point seems established by relativity to one another rather than the values of the data.

Is there a way to correct this and have it represent the absolute active users number?

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(benchmarksdf)` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Check that `Active users` is `numerics` and not `factors`.

I tried with the dataset `midwest` from package `ggplot2` and the display seems correct:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(midwest)
gg <- ggplot(midwest[1:10,],aes(x = area, y = poptotal)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=popdensity)) +
  labs(title = "Area vs Pop", subtitle = "Midwest dataset", y = "Pop", x = "Area") +
  geom_text(aes(label=county),size = 3,hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1.5)
gg
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change scale of size to continuous instead of default one.
try below code:

```
ggplot(benchmarksdf, aes(x =benchmarksdf$Avg.time.to.first.response,y= benchmarksdf$Response.rate)) + geom_point(shape=21, aes(fill=benchmarksdf$Community.name, size = benchmarksdf$Active.users)) +scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0,2100))+geom_text(aes(label=benchmarksdf$Community.name), check_overlap = T, show.legend = F, size = 3, vjust = 2) +
  labs(title = "Benchmarking Top Enterprise Communities", 
       subtitle = "Comparing top brand communities by response rate and avg. time to first response",
       y = "Response Rate %",
       x = "Avg. time to first response (days)") + scale_x_reverse () +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none',aspect.ratio = 0.8)
```

[image]